# How do I get linux commands like 'sudo' and 'apt-get' to my Windows system? I know about Chocolatey, I just want Linux commands

Tags: linux, windows

I really like the Linux command-line, while I also like Windows. Is there any way possible for me to get the Linux command-line on Windows?

Comment: Cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/) is an option. So is WSL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Answer (score 1):

apt is a packaging tool to interact with packages in linux.windows does not use any  kind of packaging system.If you want you can use wsl or vagrant.